# How do I skip specific checkstyle rules using maven

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I have an existing project on which I am trying to add checkstyle checks as part of the build. I see the following output:

```
A.java:15:1: Line contains a tab character.
B.java:16: Line has trailing spaces.
```

The error reported in `A.java` is in violation to the coding standards followed by my organization. Hence, I want to skip that rule alone for *all files* in the project.

Can someone suggest how I can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

To define a custom Checkstyle checker configuration inside your pom.xml, use the checkstyleRules parameter.

To allow tab character use FileTabCharacter module

```
<module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does the exact opposite of what I want. It reports only this issue. I want to execute all rules except this one rule.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way rather than to configure the _whole_ checkstyle ruleset by hands (
In our project checkstyle-cs plugin helped me alot - you set up all your required checkstyle rules in GUI, then feed the resulting xml to your pom (plugin - configuration - configLocation) - viola!

Answer (score 1):

Checkstyle does not offer an option that means something like "Use this configuration, *except* the following rules." Instead, you must supply a custom rule set which includes only the rules that you want to use.

You can specify the rules configuration that the Checkstyle Maven plugin shall use like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In the referenced *checkstyle.xml*, you can simply remove the unwanted rule. In your case, remove the line that says:

```xml
<module name="FileTabCharacter"/>
```

Checkstyle only executes rules which are explicity mentioned in the configuration. Here's [how to write a checkstyle.xml](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html). The default rule file is [this one](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/config/checkstyle_checks.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle 3.2 added support for [SuppressionFilter](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter)s. Public Maven repos list the release date as November 8, 2005, but they also list that same release date for several other versions, so presumably, this was the date of some migration, but the release has been available at least since then. The default Checkstyle version in the maven-checkstyle-plugin has been 4.1 [at least since January of 2006](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/history.html).

You can [configure the suppression filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html) via Maven, independently of the checkstyle config XML other answers have referenced.

A suppression config something like this should help with the scenario you shared in your question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Checkstyle//DTD SuppressionFilter Configuration 1.0//EN"
     "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">
 
<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="FileTabCharacter" files=".*\.java" />
</suppressions>
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkstyle error is not severe. You can disable checkstyle plugin, put

> `<plugin>
>           <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
>           <configuration>
>             <skip>true</skip>
>           </configuration>
>     </plugin>`

in pom.xml file

Comment: I don't want to skip all the violations. Just the tab character rule.